# How to save only edited data that retrieved from database? i'm confused. I can delete specific record but can not save only specific record

Tags: asp-classic

I need to retrieve product info. from database and now want to edit some data and save it back to database. I've created Edit Form page and passed value to the other Save page. What I want is only to save record that had been edited however when i clicked "save" button, data of all records were passed through. What i confused was with the same passing method, I can successfully delete only specific record.

Here's my code..

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" width="100%">
    <tr class="border bluebackend" >
        <td class="center bold" width="30">Size</td>
        <td class="center bold" width="30">Color</td>
        <td class="center bold" width="27%">Est. Qty (dz.)</td>
        <td class="center bold" width="30">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center bold" width="30">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
<%
dim total_qty_est, total_qty
if rsPdtn_sizeColor.eof then 
response.Write "<tr><td colspan=""3"">file not found</td></tr>"
Else                      
Do while Not rsPdtn_sizeColor.EOF

total_qty_est = rsPdtn_sizeColor.fields.item("pdtn_st_qty_est")
total_qty = total_qty + total_qty_est       

%>                                              
    <tr >
        <td class="center">
            <select name="pdtn_st_size">
                <option selected>-- size -- </option>
                <option value="L" <%=checkSelectedScript(rsPdtn_sizeColor.fields.item("pdtn_st_size"),"L")%>>L</option>
                <option value="XL" <%=checkSelectedScript(rsPdtn_sizeColor.fields.item("pdtn_st_size"),"XL")%>>XL</option>

            </select>                                                                    
        </td>
        <td class="center">
            <select name="pdtn_st_color">
                <option selected>-- color -- </option>
                <option value="Orange" <%=checkSelectedScript(rsPdtn_sizeColor.fields.item("pdtn_st_color"),"Orange")%>>Orange</option>
                <option value="Pink" <%=checkSelectedScript(rsPdtn_sizeColor.fields.item("pdtn_st_color"),"Pink")%>>Pink</option> 
            </select>                                                                         
        </td>
         <td class="center">
            <input type="text" value="<%=PcsToDz(rsPdtn_sizeColor.fields.item("pdtn_st_qty_est"))%>" name="pdtn_st_qty_est" size="3">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;(<%=rsPdtn_sizeColor.fields.item("pdtn_st_qty_est")%>)
         </td>
        <td><input type="button" name="" value="Del" onClick="confirmationDeletePrice('../engine/delPdtn_szCl.asp?pdtn_szcl_id= <%=rsPdtn_sizeColor.fields.item("pdtn_szcl_id")%>&pdtn_st_id=<%=rsPdtn_sizeColor.fields.item("tbl_pdtn_sizecolor.pdtn_st_id")%>')"></td>     
        <td class="center" >
        <input type="button" name="" value="Save" onClick="confirmationSaveProduction_Szcl('production_szcl_edit_action.asp?pdtn_szcl_id= <%=rsPdtn_sizeColor.fields.item("pdtn_szcl_id")%>')">

         <input type="hidden" value="Y" name="edit_pdtn_szcl">
          <input type="hidden" value="<%=rsPdtn_sizeColor.fields.item("pdtn_szcl_id")%>" name="pdtn_szcl_id">                                                                    
        </td>                                                               
    </tr>
<%
rsPdtn_sizeColor.movenext

Loop    
rsPdtn_sizeColor.movefirst
end if
%>
```

and this is my Save page code...

```
<%
    pdtn_st_id = Request.form("pdtn_st_id")
    pdtn_st_qty_est_dz = Request.form("pdtn_st_qty_est")

        if pdtn_st_qty_est_dz <> "" then
            pdtn_st_qty_est = DztoPcs(pdtn_st_qty_est_dz)
        end if

    pdtn_st_size =   Request.form("pdtn_st_size")   
    pdtn_st_color =   Request.form("pdtn_st_color") 
    edit_pdtn_szcl =   Request.form("edit_pdtn_szcl")   

    call checkBlank(pdtn_st_qty_est)

    if SomethingError <> "yes" then

        Call DBConnOpen()

            Set Rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
            Set Rs.ActiveConnection = Conn

            strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_pdtn_sizecolor"
                pdtn_szcl_id = Request.form("pdtn_szcl_id")
                strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE pdtn_szcl_id =" & pdtn_szcl_id & ""
                Rs.Open strSQL, Conn, 1, 3          

            Rs.Fields("pdtn_st_id") = pdtn_st_id
            Rs.Fields("pdtn_st_qty_est") = pdtn_st_qty_est
            Rs.Fields("pdtn_st_size") = pdtn_st_size    
            Rs.Fields("pdtn_st_color") = pdtn_st_color  

            Rs.Update
            Rs.Close

            response.redirect "production_view.asp?pdtn_st_id=" & pdtn_st_id

        Call DBConnClose()

    else
        call writeInputError
    end if
%>
```

Comment: This will only work if only one row is displayed, otherwise with multiple rows, because each row has identical field names the values from all rows will be combined in to one value. A quick (but not recommended) solution would be to wrap your FORM start and end tag around each table row. But a better solution will depend on whether you want to be able to edit one row at a time or all rows at once?

Comment: @John, I want to add it one at a time. So could you please suggest me what should i do in this case? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to move your existing  tags to around the table row in the loop. That way you will be able to edit one row at a time without modifying your save page code.

I have added the form tags to your code below, but you would need to use the FORM tag you are already using:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" width="100%">
    <tr class="border bluebackend" >
        <td class="center bold" width="30">Size</td>
        <td class="center bold" width="30">Color</td>
        <td class="center bold" width="27%">Est. Qty (dz.)</td>
        <td class="center bold" width="30">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center bold" width="30">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
<%
dim total_qty_est, total_qty
if rsPdtn_sizeColor.eof then 
response.Write "<tr><td colspan=""3"">file not found</td></tr>"
Else                      
Do while Not rsPdtn_sizeColor.EOF

total_qty_est = rsPdtn_sizeColor.fields.item("pdtn_st_qty_est")
total_qty = total_qty + total_qty_est       

%>
    <form action="" method=""><!--move your form open tag here-->                                       
    <tr >
        <td class="center">
            <select name="pdtn_st_size">
                <option selected>-- size -- </option>
                <option value="L" <%=checkSelectedScript(rsPdtn_sizeColor.fields.item("pdtn_st_size"),"L")%>>L</option>
                <option value="XL" <%=checkSelectedScript(rsPdtn_sizeColor.fields.item("pdtn_st_size"),"XL")%>>XL</option>

            </select>                                                                    
        </td>
        <td class="center">
            <select name="pdtn_st_color">
                <option selected>-- color -- </option>
                <option value="Orange" <%=checkSelectedScript(rsPdtn_sizeColor.fields.item("pdtn_st_color"),"Orange")%>>Orange</option>
                <option value="Pink" <%=checkSelectedScript(rsPdtn_sizeColor.fields.item("pdtn_st_color"),"Pink")%>>Pink</option> 
            </select>                                                                         
        </td>
         <td class="center">
            <input type="text" value="<%=PcsToDz(rsPdtn_sizeColor.fields.item("pdtn_st_qty_est"))%>" name="pdtn_st_qty_est" size="3">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;(<%=rsPdtn_sizeColor.fields.item("pdtn_st_qty_est")%>)
         </td>
        <td><input type="button" name="" value="Del" onClick="confirmationDeletePrice('../engine/delPdtn_szCl.asp?pdtn_szcl_id= <%=rsPdtn_sizeColor.fields.item("pdtn_szcl_id")%>&pdtn_st_id=<%=rsPdtn_sizeColor.fields.item("tbl_pdtn_sizecolor.pdtn_st_id")%>')"></td>     
        <td class="center" >
        <input type="button" name="" value="Save" onClick="confirmationSaveProduction_Szcl('production_szcl_edit_action.asp?pdtn_szcl_id= <%=rsPdtn_sizeColor.fields.item("pdtn_szcl_id")%>')">

         <input type="hidden" value="Y" name="edit_pdtn_szcl">
          <input type="hidden" value="<%=rsPdtn_sizeColor.fields.item("pdtn_szcl_id")%>" name="pdtn_szcl_id">                                                                    
        </td>                                                               
    </tr>
    </form><!--move your form close tag here-->
<%
rsPdtn_sizeColor.movenext

Loop    
rsPdtn_sizeColor.movefirst
end if
%>
```

Comment: thank you very much John. I thought with this long code, nobody will bother read it and i would not get the answer. But you did!! really thank for your kindness..